# Unable to build EntityManagerFactory Mapping XML JPA

Tags: jpa

Every time I configure `orm.xml` in the `Persistance.xml` I get the following:

***E CWWJP0015E: An error occurred in the org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence persistence provider when it attempted to create the container entity manager factory for the XYZ persistence unit. The following error occurred: PersistenceUnit: XYZ Unable to build EntityManagerFactory***

If I remove the entry from `Persistance.xml` it works fine, but the `Entity Manager is not able to locate the entity class since I am not using JPA annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Rename `Persistance.xml` to `persistence.xml`
Note that the `p` is lower case and that the word 'persistence' does not contain the letter `a`.

Also, be sure `persistence.xml` is in an appropriate location:

The following is from the **JPA spec**:

```
A persistence.xml file defines a persistence unit. The persistence.xml file is 
located in the META-INF directory of the root of the persistence unit. 
The root of the persistence unit is the key here.
```

**If you are a non-Java EE app**

```
The jar file or directory whose META-INF directory contains the persistence.xml 
file is termed the root of the persistence unit.
```

**If you are in a Java EE app, the following are valid**

In Java EE environments, the root of a persistence unit must be one of the following:

• an EJB-JAR file

• the WEB-INF/classes directory of a WAR file[80]

• a jar file in the WEB-INF/lib directory of a WAR file

• a jar file in the EAR library directory

• an application client jar file